# NextJS with Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, next.js

I want use NextJS with firebase cloud functions and I am creating a cloud function:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import cors from 'cors';
import express from 'express';
import next from 'next';

const nextApp = next({ dev: false });
const handle = nextApp.getRequestHandler();

nextApp
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express();
    server.use(cors({ origin: true }));

    server.get('/a', (req, res) => {
      return nextApp.render(req, res, '/b', req.query);
    });

    server.get('/b', (req, res) => {
      return nextApp.render(req, res, '/a', req.query);
    });

    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res);
    });
  })
  .catch(ex => {
    console.error(ex.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  });

export let app = functions.https.onRequest(nextApp);
```

NextJS create a folder with the build of my JS app.

The problem is that I can't upload on the cloud the NextJS build folder.
How I can include this folder?

GitHub Issue => https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/2017

Answer (score 4):

I must run `firebase deploy` in to `functions` directory instead of `root`.
Here my repo => https://github.com/sarovin/next-firebase-functions

Answer (score 2):

Firebase currently ignores uploading hidden files in Cloud Functions. A [PR](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/381) has been merged to fix this, but I believe is still unreleased at this time.

Once you have this sorted you'll find you come across a number of other issues with hosting Next.js on Cloud Functions. For example, JS bundles are stored at the `/_next/` route and are not accessible unless you use the correct Firebase Hosting rewrite rules.

I've written [a blog post](https://medium.com/@jthegedus/next-js-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase-with-firebase-hosting-7911465298f2) covering all issues and caveats that I discovered when getting Next.js to work on Cloud Functions.